# How to assign current year in with tag

Tags: django, django-templates

In django I want to do something like this, which will pass current year to url name

```
{% with now "Y" as year %}
<a href="{% url 'createAwardWinner' year  %}"><i class="fa fa-gavel fa-fw"></i> Create</a>
{% endwith %}
```

but its not able to interpret I want to do

> year = now 'Y'

How should I do this

Comment: What happens if you put Y in single quotes: ```{% with now 'Y' as year %}```? That may be your only problem

Comment: @ISOmetric `url(r'^dashboard/show/(?P<year>\d{4})/awardWinners/$', HomeViews.createawardWinners.as_view(), name='createAwardWinner'),`            Year will be passed in to url

Comment: @ISOmetric It doesn't matter if its a single quotes or double. just don't need with tag here. simply doing what bastien roques said does the trick.

Comment: Great - you should accept his answer as correct

Comment: as soon as SO lets me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you simply try:

```
{% now "Y" as current_year %}
<a href="{% url 'createAwardWinner' current_year  %}"><i class="fa fa-gavel fa-fw"></i> Create</a>
```

Comment: Perfect, This is what I was looking for. Thanks